# How to implement this in HTML

Tags: html, layout

I wanted to implement this layout in HTML, however I am sure how to do the round element and the "edge/corner[image]" (red). How would you do it?

Comment: wherever you have seen just place mouse pointer and right click and select inpect element, you can check code there, you will come to know how it can be done. however it also uses CSS for the designing...you need to do css part also otherthan html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it requests for visual design for a (vaguely) described layout rather than a specific coding question.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I do believe it does take programming to make a layout. Therefore, this question is still on topic, since he is asking HOW to achieve this layout. Am i correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do this, you can either use css to create that triangle, or you have to use a image and vertically align it with your div. For rounded corners, you can use `border-radius`

to make the triangle in css:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `border-radius` property.

```
.round
{
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:red;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v4fW4/)

Comment: HI I am almost done, however the text is not aligned correctly, can you help me ? http://jsfiddle.net/Lf4sr/